# Jenkins - Can't download upgrades / plugins - Proxy is already set - Able to reach .hpi via http fine in IE

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I got the Windows Native .zip from Jenkins site and installed Jenkins on my machine (Win 7) as Windows service.

The nice dashboard is up and now I want to download some plugins / even upgrade the version (First) as I got the .zip few weeks back.

When I tried to upgrade / download the plugins (under Manage Jenkins), I'm getting the following error messages, any idea what I could be missing.

Under Plugin's ADVANCE tab, I have provided the proxy server and port. Another point I noticed that when I'm downloading a plugin (and it fails) showing the link to the plugin .hpi file, if I use that "http ://../../.hpi" in Internet Explorer, it pops up fine (telling me to open/save etc) so in one sense, I'm able to reach the .hpi file directly. I can download the .hpi file manually and put it under the Jenkins installation/..respective/../../folder and restart Jenkins service everytime I install a new/replace an existing .hpi, but that I dont want to do that.

**Installing Plugins/Upgrades**

```
Preparation 

    Checking internet connectivity
    Checking update center connectivity
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.testConnection(UpdateCenter.java:860) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.checkUpdateCenter(UpdateCenter.java:709) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$ConnectionCheckJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1030) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 

jenkins.war 
Failure -

hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/1.508/jenkins.war
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:782)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1123)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:752)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:751)
    ... 8 more

Preparation 

    Checking internet connectivity
    Checking update center connectivity
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json?uctest at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.testConnection(UpdateCenter.java:860) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.checkUpdateCenter(UpdateCenter.java:709) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$ConnectionCheckJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1030) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 

Timestamper 
Failure -

hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/timestamper/1.5.3/timestamper.hpi
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:782)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1123)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1285)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/timestamper/1.5.3/timestamper.hpi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:752)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/timestamper/1.5.3/timestamper.hpi
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:751)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 12):

Since our update center server does not do any authentication and therefore never returns 403, most likely the 403 error is returned by your HTTP proxy. If I were you, I'd check the proxy user name and the password.

We should probably add a connectivity check button in the configuration page where you enter the proxy details. If you'd be so kind to file this as a ticket in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/, I'd be happy to get to that.

Comment: Thanks Kohsuke. I added this per your request. Ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20191

Comment: I'm having the same error - however, Jenkins doesn't allow me to save my proxy configuration. I don't have a proxy server and the "test" is always successful. It also uses my username and password (logged in user) without allowing me to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kohsuke. Issue was I was using the proxy hostname with http://proxyservername.com.

When I put "proxyservername.com", it worked. I'll open a ticket to get that "Test" Proxy connection button in. Would have been nice if (?) shows an example, but my bad.